# Templated classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Below is my code. I am using the GNU G++ compiler. I am getting error "main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:9: error: ‘class hash’ has no member named ‘printVectorContents’"

I know I am overlooking something stupid I just can't put my finger on it. Any help?

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Yeah you did dat"<<std::endl;
    hash<int> newHash;
    newHash.printVectorContents();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and my templated class...

```
template <class dataTypeClass> class hash{
private:
    std::vector <dataTypeClass> hashVector;
    std::string mName;
public:
    hash(){}
    hash(std::string aName = "unnamedHash"):mName(aName),hashVector(100,NULL){}
    ~hash(){std::cout<<"Hash "<<mName<<"destructing!";}
    void addHashItem(dataTypeClass aHashItem, std::string akey){}
    int hashFunction(dataTypeClass hashItem){return 0;}
    void printVectorContents()
    {
        for (typename std::vector<dataTypeClass>::iterator i = hashVector.begin(); i<hashVector.rend(); i++)
        {
            std::cout<< *i << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that `hash<int>` refers to `std::hash<int>` rather than your class template? Since you clearly didn't show a complete translation unit, its hard to tell what you got in your translation unit.

Comment: What compiler you are use? Seems, it look like borland turbo C++ 3.0 from 19xx years. Your code have several other errors discovered by modern compilators.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't also getting an error in printVectorContents()? E.g. at "i<hashVector.rend()" (don't you mean ".end()"?). See if you still get an error once you fix it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Next time I'll be sure to never offend you oh great and mighty C++ God of the mystical StackOverflow. I shall make sure to sacrifice my first born in your name for my trespasses today. Clearly you are infallible and I should suffer.

Comment: @Torsten I am using the GNU G++ compiler with -wall on. It's just what I am used to from academia. I realized I was implementing my template class wrong. What type of errors where you seeing?

Comment: @DS Yeah I did I was confused as to how I originally wanted to pring it and when I got the other errors I got distracted. 

Upvotes for everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `hash` is a common name, make it `myhash`, etc. or place it into its own namespace to avoid name clashes.
2. Remove `hash(){}`. You have a constructor taking a default parameter already, when you declare `hash<int> myhash;`, it doesn't know which constructor to call.
3. Change `i<hashVector.rend()` to `i != hashVector.end()`.
4. Change `hashVector(100,NULL)` to `hashVector(100)`.

Comment: These were all things I needed to change thank you. Though they did not fix my original error. I came to realize that I had a header file and cpp file for a template class which is wrong. That was causing most of my problems.  http://bit.ly/UNpwY9   I am coming back to c++ from doing C# for a while and I got a little adventurous trying to do too many things at once.